# Why is there no article "the" before "bed" in "in bed"?

Tags: articles

Jamaica Inn episode 5 from BBC learning English drama section:

The dialogue says:

> Mary: My aunt is in bed.

She doesn't say -

> My aunt is in the bed.

That section is for teaching English.  Are they using incorrect English?

Comment: Can you please explain why you think "the" is necessary here?

Comment: @Catija I thought the is used before things. I live in a non native English speaking country and every one here says please sit on the chair.

Comment: @Catija *In bed* is actually rather exceptional grammatically.  Similar examples include *in hospital* (BrE), *in prison,* or *in school*.  I don't really know of a good way to explain them other than to call them exceptions.  They're covered in the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, but only very briefly, on page 409.  I suppose if I were a learner, I'd just memorize them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is correct (read "grammatical"). Though ***bed*** is normally used as a countable noun, it's better to think of it in ***in bed*** as uncountable.

This is common in common fixed expressions about place, time, and movement.

Here are examples of such expressions (according to *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, 70.1 common expressions without articles):

> *to/at/in/from school/university/college
>
>   to/at/in/into/from church
>
>   to/in/into/out of bed/prison
>
>   to/in/into/out of hospital* (BrE)
>   *to/at/from work
>
>   to/at sea
>
>   to/in/from town
>
>   at/from home
>
>   leave home
>
>   leave/start/enter school/university/college
>
>   by day
>
>   at night
>
>   by car/bus/bicycle/plane/train/tube/boat
>
>   on foot
>
>   by radio/phone/letter/mail*

Also note that even though these fixed expressions are commonly used without any article, you can use an article if it's appropriate in your context.

In other words, you can use such a noun with *a/an* or *the*, or even in the plural (e.g. *I've lived in several towns*), but keep in mind that it will convey a subtly different meaning.

For example,

- *Have you tried the new bed yet?*
- (a department store trainee asking the manager) *What should I do if a customer wants to sleep in a bed?*
- (an example of such fixed expressions) *"Where's your sister?" "She's still in bed." "Wake her up!"*

The main factor for choosing the right article or omitting the article is, as always: *context!*

---

Bonus: Some dictionaries that keep English language learners in mind may make it a little clearer by defining these nouns in common fixed expressions as both "countable" and "uncountable". For example, here is the first definition of ***bed*** given by Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[bed](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bed_1)**
>   [countable/uncountable] a piece of furniture that you sleep on, consisting of a soft comfortable part called a mattress and a base
>   **double/twin/single bed**: *The room had two single beds in it.*
>   **out of/in bed**: *It’s midnight – why aren’t you in bed?*
>   **get out of bed (=get up)**: *I never get out of bed before 10 a.m.*
>   **go to bed**: *I’ll get home at 11 p.m. and go straight to bed.*
>   **put someone to bed**: *Sam was upstairs putting the children to bed.*
>   **make the/my/your etc. bed (=make its covers straight after you have slept in it)**: *Why can’t you kids make your own beds?*

You can use these dictionaries to verify the noun in a fixed expression you may find while reading or listening to your materials.

Comment: But one can very definitely say *the bed*, as in *My aunt is in the bed by the corner* or *Aunt, you just lie down in the bed here and rest.* This for the OP, as I'm sure you @DamkerngT know this. Both my examples use *the* to make a definite reference to a particular bed.

Comment: @pazzo so, we have to use article the while referring to a particular bed? Anyways, if I say aunt is in the bed , will it be wrong?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius (Because pazzo's still not here. :-) In those fixed expressions, you can use the noun with *a/an* or *the*, or even in the plural (e.g. *I've lived in several towns*), but it will convey a different meaning. For example, *Have you tried the new bed yet?*, (a department store trainee asking the manager) *What should I do if a customer want to sleep in a bed?*, but *Where's your sister? She's still in bed. Wake her up!* So, it's possible, but not "have to". The main factor for choosing the right article is as usual: context!

Comment: @DamkerngT. please add that valuable info to your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius As you like it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I find the idea to consider bed  uncountable really funny, even if some dictionaries say so. English has a strong tendency to drop the definite article when it achieves next to nothing. The aunt sleeps in the bed she sleeps every day in, so why say "in the bed" when the shorter "in bed" says exactly the same. By omitting the article "bed" doesn't become uncountable. I would say such theories taken from the air confuse learners still more. They must think English is a queer language.

The same phenomenon can be seen in German. Instead of "in dem Bett" (in the bed) German contracts "in dem" to "im" and says "im Bett" (in bed) to get a shorter expression.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you think such an idea (these nouns in common fixed expressions are uncountable) is funny, though apparently, dictionaries treat them that way. In any case, the learner will have only a few choices to understand these nouns in these expressions: thinking of the nouns as uncountable, looking for the mysterious zero articles, or just remembering the whole list of these expressions. (Personally, I think the zero articles is a little funnier.) I really don't know which way will confuse the learner more. However, everyone is entitled to their own opinions.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think that learners have to be confused for a while, one way or the other. I've been learning English for longer than I care to remember and articles (the articles? see, it's terrible) are still killing me :-). @ rogermue I understand that you used the example from German to make a point that omitting the article is a way of being rational with words, but "im = in+dem", "ins = in das" still contain the article (you can easily distinguish that *im* is dative and *ins* accusative), so a learner who is a native German speaker might be confused by such an example

Comment: Yes, rogermue, I agree that stating that bed is uncountable seems arbitrary (@DamkerngT.), but not any less arbitrary than saying English does away with the definite article when it achieves next to nothing. We don't generally say *mom's in kitchen* even though there's only one kitchen in >99% of homes of native English speakers.