# Which is right? After school vs after the school?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I wonder which sentence is the right one.

> What are you going to do after school?

vs

> What are you going to do after the school?

To me, I feel like "after the school" is the right one, but I might saw "after school" on the TV before.

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate of): [Why is there no article “the” before “bed” in “in bed”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/59205/3281)

Comment: In Short - "after school" is the correct reponse.