# What this construction is called, "have time", "go to university"

Tags: verbs, adverbs

Consider the following constructions. **take lessons, give lessens, take a nap, take a shower, go to sleep, go to school, have time, spend time, <s>play football</s>, suffer damage, do homework, do a mistake, make a mistake, make a decision, say prayers, ...**

- What such constructions are called? (compound
  verb? phrasal verb? idioms?....)
- What is the role of the noun (school, time, damage) in these constructions? are they all adverbs or part of an adverbial phrase?
- Why the noun in these construction doesn't take any article? Does it make them generic? if they are even countable?
- How can I distinguish them? Why I can say *go to school* but not *go to jungle*?

For some of them like (*go to sleep, take lessens, have time, take a nap*) the verb (*do, take, have*) without the noun has less meaning in the context.

Comment: As a note, "go to hospital" and "go to university" and some other similar constructions are common in British English but are not used in American English, so what may be OK in some version of English isn't necessarily ok in another.

Comment: @Catija then what they use to say *go to university* or *go to hospital*, as they are also present in Persian too.

Comment: We (I'm an American) say "I'm going to *the* hospital." ... We don't say "go to university" but that's mostly because we say "go to college". We don't tend to use "university" in the same way they do in BrE.

Comment: Can I ask you **why** you would like to give a name to these types of constructions? What are you trying to achieve by having one?

Comment: @JMB In this day of information, wouldn't you think that knowing the name of something would make it easier to learn about it? Searching the web for "white and black animal" gives you many different animals to choose from but searching for "zebra" gives you only one.

Comment: @Catija Sure, I get that. However, I feel that given the seemingly wide range of phrases the OP gave, he might be better off simply learning verb + noun phrases that don't require an article as he finds them. I just wasn't sure there is a tangible group word to give him.

Comment: @JMB They all have something in common and I was looking for that similarity, if you see exceptions please let me know, for example *say prayers* is neither *say* nor *prayers*, *go to school* doesn't mean going to a specific place, but it just means to start education.... in Persian we call them compound verbs (if I don't mistake)

Comment: They are not quite the same thing, even though all of them could be considered "verb phrases" (VP). Also, it may be a good idea to separate what they are from their functions. Let's try *I go to school* and *I play football*. *Go to school* is a VP; so is *play football*. *To school* is a prepositional phrase, but *football* is a noun. *To school* functions as an adverb (thus we can call it an "adverbial prepositional phrase"), but *football* is the "object" of that sentence. IMHO, your questions are not tightly related, and thus this ELL Question is too broad.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You may be right. Please post your answer and explain it more so I can get what is "verb phrase"?!

Comment: Thanks for the invitation! however, I sincerely think that some questions in this Question are better asked on their own. For example, an old answer of mine, [Why is there no article “the” before “bed” in “in bed”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/59215/3281), may address the article issue more adequately. As for "verb phrase", as far as I can tell, most people seem to use the term to include everything in a clause except the subject, but others use it to refer to only the verb group. This so called "narrow definition" of "verb phrase" is discussed shortly on [Wikipedia](https://goo.gl/frAvsc).

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to find an English parallel to Persian compound verbs, constructions with a 'light verb' and a non-verb which we call complex predicates. This is *way* over my head in both languages, and I have asked one of our contributors, a native speaker of Persian, to lend a hand; but I can tell you that these constructions are so uncommon in English that they are rarely addressed in any but the most sophisticated linguistic analysis.

Comment: @StoneyB Then you pointed to complex predicates, maybe you can bring examples of them? yes in Persian most compound verbs are something like *do homework* or *give lessen* where *do* and *give* are light verbs, however *go, hit, beat* or any other verb could play that role too. for example *melt = go/become + water* in Persian

Comment: @StoneyB Also, I used Persian compound verbs analogy to find an answer to the question, the comparison is not my end in this question. I want to distinguish complex predicates as you said and the examples I broughtt about for example *go to school* and ...