# What is the difference between "at school" and "at the school"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-article

What is the difference in meaning between ***at school*** and ***at the school***?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59205/why-is-there-no-article-the-before-bed-in-in-bed.

Answer (score 2):

When we say

**She is at school.**

we are not identifying or specifying which school.  She is not at home, she is at school, whichever school it may happen to be.

When we say

**She is at the school.**

we are indicating that we have a particular school in mind, which the listener knows either from something said earlier in the conversation or from some other contextual information.